# Add a condition to allow a scan

Tags: react-native, conditional-statements

I want to add a condition in my code and for that, I would like your help.
To explain the purpose of this screen: I have a camera used to scan tickets at an event.
I want to force the user to first choose the event for which he wants to scan the ticket thanks to the implementation of an autocomplete input that I made thanks to the package

> 'react-native-dropdown-autocomplete'

So, I don't really know how to do this, adding a condition to prevent the user from scanning his QrCode / Barcode before having selected his event.
Where do you think I can put my condition? And how do you put it in place ?

Thanks for all the time you spent helping me. :)

```
class Tickets extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Press: false,
      hasCameraPermission: null,
      name: '',
      lastScannedUrl:null,
      displayArray: []      
    };
  }
   initListData = async () => {
    let list = await getProducts(1);
   
    if (list) {
      this.setState({
        displayArray: list,
        name: list.name
      });      
    }
    //console.log('reference dans initListData =', list.reference)
  };

  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.initListData();
    //console.log('reference dans le state =', this.state.reference)
};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermissionsAsync(); 
  }

  getPermissionsAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === "granted" });
  };

  handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    this.setState({ Press: false, scanned: true, reference: data });
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {reference : parseInt(this.state.state.reference)})
  };

  renderBarcodeReader = () => {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned } = this.state;

    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <Text>{i18n.t("scan.request")}</Text>;
    }
    if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>{i18n.t("scan.noaccess")}</Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
        }}
      >   
      <Camera
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : this.handleBarCodeScanned}
        barCodeScannerSettings={[Camera.Constants.Type.qr]}
        style={{flex:1}}
      />
        {scanned && (
          <Button
            title={"Tap to Scan Again"}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ scanned: false })}
          />
        )}    
      </View>
    );
  }
  handleSelectItem(item, index) {
    const {onDropdownClose} = this.props;
    onDropdownClose();
    console.log(item);
  }
  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned, Press } = this.state;
    let marker = null;

    const {scrollToInput, onDropdownClose, onDropdownShow} = this.props;

 console.log('displayArray', this.state.displayArray, 'reference', this.state.displayArray.name)

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{zIndex:100, color: 'red', fontStyle: 'italic', fontSize: 14}}>{i18n.t("tickets.warning")}</Text> 
        <View style={{width: "100%", zIndex: 100}}>                         
          <Autocomplete
            key={shortid.generate()}
            containerStyle={{margin: 0, padding: 0, borderBottomColor: 'transparent',}}
            inputStyle={{ width: '80%', borderWidth: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFF', opacity: 0.9, borderColor: '#F78400'}}
            placeholder={i18n.t("tickets.event")}
            placeholderColor="#F78400"
            pickerStyle={styles.autocompletePicker}
            scrollStyle={styles.autocompleteScroll}
            scrollToInput={ev => {}}
            handleSelectItem={(item, id) => this.handleSelectItem(item, id)}
            onDropdownClose={() => onDropdownClose()}
            onDropdownShow={() => onDropdownShow()}              
            fetchDataUrl={Api}
            minimumCharactersCount={2}
            highlightText
            valueExtractor={item => item.name}
            rightContent
            rightTextExtractor={item => item.properties}
          />
        </View>
          {this.renderBarcodeReader()}                 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Tickets;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to maintain the selectedItem in the state

```
this.state = {
      Press: false,
      hasCameraPermission: null,
      name: '',
      lastScannedUrl:null,
      displayArray: [],
     selectedItem:null  // this should be added
    };
```

Then set that from handleSelectItem

```
handleSelectItem=(item, index)=> {
    const {onDropdownClose} = this.props;
    onDropdownClose();
    console.log(item);

   this.setState({
     selectedItem:item
   });
  }
```

And you can disable the button based on that

```
<Button
        title={"Tap to Scan Again"}
        onPress={() => this.setState({ scanned: false })}
        disabled={this.state.selectedItem===null}
      />
```

The button would be disabled until you select an item, or you can conditionally call renderBarcodeReader based on this.state.selectedItem

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for your time and explanations ! I'm truly very grateful !  :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add conditional checking if you have event selected before rendering the  component. When there isnt event selected display black block with border (something like this maybe => https://ibb.co/8mMtNBB) and only render  if event is selected. Alternatively, you can add the same boolean that indicates wether an even has been selected to the on onBarCodeScanned method and call your function only if there's an event selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)